# How to display 2D probabilistic map in rviz?

Tags: navigation, mapping, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a probability grid that I use as a map in my application.

How can I display this in rviz? Does the rviz map plugin supports probability values or only the states unknown, occupied and free?

Is there any other option on how can I show this map in an user friendly way?

I found this question here [Rviz display 2d probabilistic map](http://answers.ros.org/question/12914/rviz-display-2d-probabilistic-map/), but, since it's from February 2012, I wanted to get a more updated answer on this topic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191432/how-to-display-2d-probabilistic-map-in-rviz?/) by [t.pimentel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4923/t.pimentel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2014-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RViz can show [nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html) messages both as grayscale or with a color scheme. I think this is exactly what you need, given you can convert your probabilities to a 0..255 range.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2014-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1